# Microsoft Access Query Find Unmatched Query Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have an access query used from "Find Unmatched Query Wizard".  Table FM31.Credits contains three rows with $300.00 and REO1.Amount contains one row of $300.00. I need the query to return the two rows with $300.00 since there is only one match, but my query doesn't return any rows of $300.00 because it found one match. What am I missing? I copied the sql view code below. Thanks.

SELECT [FM31-New].POSTDATE, [FM31-New].CREDITS
FROM [FM31-New] LEFT JOIN [RE01-New] ON [FM31-New].[CREDITS] = [RE01-New].[AMOUNT]
WHERE ((([RE01-New].AMOUNT) Is Null));

Comment: Are you working with Access or sql server? And of course it won't return the row in question because there IS a match. This query will find rows that don't match.

Comment: Dont you have any other columns that you can link between FM31.Credits and REO1.Amount?

Comment: It's in Access. One table (report) has the account number and the other table (report) does not so we are matching by currency field. Not the best practice I know, but it's the only field available to match. How can I revise it to do a one to one match?